# How to build a custom "navigation" sidebar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an Android app, cooperating with an iOS developer who created the design. It should be using two side menus, with the ability to slide in from left or right. Now, I have created two NavigationViews in a DrawerLayout (with the support libary). Is it possible to have other elements than a listview in this sidebar, like a slider or ImageView?

[image: Look at the design here.]

Comment: For those downvoting, please explain what is wrong about this question. It it just not done according to Android Guidelines? If so, what should be the proper cause of action? A link to a new settings-activity?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have other elements than a listview in this sidebar, like a slider or ImageView?

If I remember correctly, YES.
When I started learning about NavigationViews & DrawerLayout I read through [**this**](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) blog post. If `DrawLayout` is the root element you should be able to add other child elements apart from `ListView` but I recommend you read through it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create with this 3 classes:

1.NavigationDrawerItem

```
public class NavigationDrawerItem {

private String title;
private int imageId;
private int layoutId;

public int getLayoutId() {
    return layoutId;
}

public void setLayoutId(int layoutId) {
    this.layoutId = layoutId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public static List<NavigationDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavigationDrawerItem> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] imageIds = getImages();
    String[] titles = getTitles();
    int[] ids = getId();

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavigationDrawerItem navItem = new NavigationDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        navItem.setImageId(imageIds[i]);
        navItem.setLayoutId(ids[i]);
        dataList.add(navItem);
    }
    return dataList;
}

private static int[] getId() {
       return new int[] {0};
}

private static int[] getImages() {

    return new int[]{R.drawable.icon_settings};
}

private static String[] getTitles() {

    return new String[] {"Settings"};
}}
```

2.NavigationDrawerAdapter

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<NavigationDrawerItem> mDataList = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
public  int drawerOnclickID;

public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavigationDrawerItem> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mDataList = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_list_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NavigationDrawerItem current = mDataList.get(position);

    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(current.getImageId());
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    drawerOnclickID = current.getLayoutId();
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, holder.title.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    holder.setListener();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title;
    ImageView imgIcon;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_drawer_listener);
    }


    public void setListener() {
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Intent intent;


        switch (drawerOnclickID){


            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(context,Settings.class);
                break;
            default:
                intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

3.NavigationDrawerFragment

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    setUpRecyclerView(view);

    return view;
}

private void setUpRecyclerView(View view) {

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), NavigationDrawerItem.getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}

public void setUpDrawer(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
           //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            // Do something of Slide of Drawer`
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });}}
```

MainActivity onCreate

```
        setUpDrawer();
```

setUpDrawer

```
private void setUpDrawer() {
    NavigationDrawerFragment     drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_drwr_fragment);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerFragment.setUpDrawer(R.id.nav_drwr_fragment,drawerLayout,toolbar);
}
```

XML

1.fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

2.nav_drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout_drawer_listener"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_play"
    android:tint="@color/grey_500" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"   />
```

Finally in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drwr_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.sobi.speedcamera.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```